# Draw scaled TextView on Bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, textview, scale

i want to draw a text to a scaled bitmap.

I have a realtive Layout where i can drag and drop the TextView.

An "save" Button creats a scaled bitmap and i want to place the TextView at the same position on the bitmap as on the relative layout.

As far i am trying this:

```
    Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(postcard.getWidth(), postcard.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.setBitmap(finalBitmap);

        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setColor(fct.getTextColor());
        p.setTextSize(fct.getTextSize());
        p.setTypeface(fct.getFont().getTypeFace(ctx));

        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        p.getTextBounds(fct.getText(), 0, fct.getText().length(), bounds);
        int x = (int) (fct.getPositionX() - bounds.width()/2);
        int y = (int) (bounds.height() + fct.getPositionY());
        canvas.drawText(fct.getText(), x, y, p);
```

But the result is not good !

The TextView isnt placed at the same location as on the relative layout.

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a bitmap exactly like a view, why not just draw the view on a bitmap?

You can first draw a bitmap at the same size as your view, and then scale the bitmap.

```
   Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(),
            Config.ARGB_8888);
   v.draw(new Canvas(bmp));
   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
   return Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), 
                          matrix, true);
```

Comment: yep, thats a good idea but does it also work with low resolutions displays?

Comment: @user1948160 No, bitmap should not be scaled up. But maybe you can still use an offscreen view to draw this.